# correct way to break promise chain on first rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, q

I have a promise chain which requires rejection to be handled differently for individual steps:

```
serviceA.getData()
    .then(
        function(dataA) {
            return serviceB.getData(dataA);
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(404).end();
        }
    )
    .then(
        function(dataB) {
            return serviceC.getData(dataB);
        }, function(err) {
            res.status(401).end();
        }
    )
    .done();
```

When `serviceA.getData()` promise is rejected, I want promise chain to be interrupted after first rejection handler executes. Instead, both rejection handlers get executed.

Couldn't find an answer in [Q docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Suggestions?

Comment: That's the way promises are supposed to work, you could place your code in a `try-catch` block and pass information about the kind of error that happened to the outer (try catch) code from within your rejection handlers by `throw`ing exceptions.

Comment: maybe also see [Break promise chain and call a function based on the step in the chain where it is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20714460/1048572)