# How i prevent calling nested then method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I have login api and nested then function is there, my question is how I stop from calling as certain condition, pasting my code:

```
login(values.email, values.password)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res?.value?.data?.unverified) {
      console.log('>>> in', res, RESEND_VERIFICATION_EMAIL_DIALOG);
    } else getMe(true);
  })
  .then(() => ...)
```

So, if it comes in the above if I have to stop calling nested then and all code.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :).

Comment: Instead of `then` you could try the `async` and `await` method

Comment: It's not possible because i have too many conditions inside another then

Comment: If there is no intermediate catch block, you can throw an error

Comment: a) you are not calling nested `.then()`? What are you trying to do? b) if you would, it wouldn't be bad!

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use `.then, .catch`

```
login(values.email, values.password)
.then((res) => {
    if (res?.value?.data?.unverified) {
      console.log('>>> in', res, RESEND_VERIFICATION_EMAIL_DIALOG);
    } else getMe(true);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e); // "oh, no!"
});
```

PS: I found a good [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it) about stopping the promise chain which I hope would help you

Comment: I already have catch, i think you are not getting my question I have to stop calling another then in 200 response.

Comment: I've put a link to a post with the same purpose.